# How to use expressions in if statements in DBT

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

I want to know how, if possible, I can use dbt expressions that are enclosed in two curly brackets (`{{ }}`), inside a statement that is enclosed in a curly bracket and a percent sign (`{% %}`).

For example, I want to execute a piece of code in DBT if the table exists. In my head, it would look something like:

```
{% if {{this}} is not none %}

    do something

{% endif %}
```

But there's a syntax issue here and I can't seem to be able to use expressions inside statement blocks. I have seen the following implementation but I want to know how I can replace `source` with `{{this}}`.

```
{% set table_exists=source('db', 'table') is not none %}

{% if table_exists %}

   do something

{% endif %}
```

These are the docs I have read:

- ['this' jinja function](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/this)
- [jinja and macros](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/jinja-macros)
- [dbt if table exists example](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/writing-packages-when-a-source-table-may-or-may-not-exist/1487)
- [using load_relation to check if model exists](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/adapter)

---

Comment: Wondering if you could assign the value of {{ this }} to a variable, and then use that variable inside the {% if %}?

Comment: No because when assigning variables you do `{% set varname = ... %}` and you can't nest curlies so...

Comment: I was expecting (and referring to) the behaviour described in the accepted answer, though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Don't Nest Your Curlies](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/dont-nest-your-curlies)

If you're inside either `{{ ... }}` or `{% ... %}`, your code will be executed by the jinja templating engine. `this` is a variable that is already set in the jinja context. You use `{{ this }}` in SQL, but if you're already in the jinja context provided by `{% ... %}`, you can just write `this`, without the curlies.

Your if block becomes:

```sql
{% if this is not none %}

    do something

{% endif %}
```